# Using adverb before or after a verb, what is the difference?

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs

I have seen following two varients of the sentences

> John and the team have worked tirelessly

and

> John and the team have tirelessly worked

I believe "tirelessly" is an adverb. Which of the above sentences is correct? If both the sentences are correct, when to use which form?

Comment: The question is not about correctness. It's about idiom...the way people speak. Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that **worked tirelessly** is many times more common than the reverse.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&corpus=26&content=worked+tirelessly%2Ctirelessly+worked&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworked%20tirelessly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctirelessly%20worked%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cworked%20tirelessly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctirelessly%20worked%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While English is usually very strict about word order, when it comes to adverbs and the verb they modify, it can go either way. You can say "we worked tirelessly" or "we tirelessly worked". Both mean the same thing.

Without doing a statistical analysis, I think we usually put the adverb after the verb. "I worked tirelessly", "I ran quickly to the door", "I grabbed selfishly", etc.

Just to make it more complicated, if the verb has a direct object, you can put the adverb before the verb or after the direct object, but not between the verb and the direct object. Like you could say, "I suddenly found the solution", or you could also say, "I found the solution suddenly." But a fluent speaker would NOT say, "I found suddenly the solution."

As to when to put the adverb first and when to put it later, I can't think of any general rule. If someone else on here can suggest a rule, I'm happy to hear it. I think it's mostly about emphasis. If the adverb is important, you tend to put it after. Like if I said, "I worked tirelessly", that puts more emphasis on the claim that I was tireless, but if I said "I tirelessly worked", that puts more emphasis on the fact that I simply worked. But it's often a very subtle difference.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, tirelessly is a verb. Both of them are absolutely correct.

Although people prefer using the adverb before the verb. If an adverb strongly modifies the main verb, put it before the main verb, not after the first helping verb (in a compound verb with three or more words.

A verb is a word for an action or a state of being. An adverb is a word used to modify a verb, an adjective, or another adverb.

Therefore using the first one would be more appropriate

Comment: Tirelessly is ... not a verb.